# C++ average of negative elements in array

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to find the average of the negative elements in the two-dimensional array. This is what I've got so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int A[3][3];
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << "\n A[" << i + 1 << "][" << j + 1 <<"]=";
            cin >> A[i][j];
        }

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << A[i][j] << "\t";

        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: And?  You forgot to ask an actual question.

Comment: You don't perform any arithmetic. Do you know how to sum values, test if they are negative, count?

Comment: ok i tryed to find the sum of i with this for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 sum += A[i];
cout<<sum;

Comment: but there is an error '+ =': illegal, right operand has type 'int [3]'

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between `+` and `=`. The operator is `+=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it for example:

```
int negNumber = 0;
int sum = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    if (A[i][j] < 0) {
      ++negNumber; // increase negatives numbers found
      sum += A[i][j]; // add to our result the number
    }
  }
}

sum = negNumber > 0 ? sum / negNumber : sum; // we need to check if we found at least one negative number
```

I hope it will help you but be careful! It will return a truncated value (an int).

the [ternary operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) could be difficult to undertand so you can do it:

```
if (negNumber > 0) {
  sum /= negNumber;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that this returns a truncated average.

Comment: Indeed. Since it's an `int array` I thought the sum must be an `integer` too, but it was a mistake sorry.